# Is 'form' an acceptable struct tag to use when parsing URL query parameters into a struct?

Tags: http, go, struct, parameters

I've got a GET request function that takes in query parameters using `gin.Context`. I'm currently passing those query parameters using `context.ShouldBindQuery(&myQueryParamStruct)` into a struct that looks like

```
type myParams struct {
    Color string `form:"color"`
    Size  int    `form:"size"`
}
```

My question is will issues arise when using the form tag to do this (since I'm not technically using a form, I'm using query parameters), and is there a better struct tag for this purpose?

Comment: the naming of the tags is completely internal to the API that defines and consume them. It wont mix up things. `is there a better struct tag for this purpose` unclear what you do, maybe the api provide more appropriate tag to perform the decoding you are implementing, but you have to explain more accurately your goal so someone might help, or more simply, read the doc to figure out what it provides in regards of what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form` is the correct tag, you needn't worry.

Note also that html forms sent using the GET request are sent in the query string rather than the body. Furthermore, query strings and form bodies both have the application/x-www-**form**-urlencoded format.